# Каким образом можно отрефакторить метод getAllProjects() в реализации сервиса?

Tags: java

У меня есть следующий [сервис](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/application/service/impl/ProjectServiceImpl.java#L18) с реализацией внутри проекта:

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectAdaptor projectAdaptor;

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAll() {
        return projectRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllProjects(Long companyId) {
        return projectRepository.getAll().stream()
                .filter(project -> project.getId() == companyId).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Project save(Project project) {
        return projectRepository.save(project);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProjectDTO> findAllProducts() {
        List<Project> project = projectRepository.findAll();
        return projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDtoList(project);
    }
}
```

В котором есть [метод](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/29aaf7cf5c4883a096e2b32c76488fb5) `getAll()`:

```
@Override
public List<Project> getAll() { 
 return projectRepository.findAll();    
}
```

и соответственно к нему `getAllProjects()`:

```
@Override 
public List<Project> getAllProjects(Long companyId) { 
  return projectRepository
   .getAll() 
   .stream() 
   .filter(project -> project.getId() == companyId) 
   .findAny() 
   .orElse(null); 
}
```

В связи с этим вопрос, каким образом отрефакторить вышепоказанный метод, который воспроизводит ошибку компиляции, связанную с типом `Object`:

> Cannot resolve method `getId` in `Object`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя сущность `Project` имеет следующую структуру:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "project_entity")
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    public Project(ProjectDTO projectDTO) {
        this.name = projectDTO.getName();
        this.abbreviation = projectDTO.getAbbreviation();
        this.customer = projectDTO.getCustomer();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String abbreviation;

    private String customer;
}
```

Нужно ли мне добавлять дополнительные аннотации `Lombok` над сущностью, чтобы решить данную проблему или есть способ просто объединить два метода в один в более правильном виде?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь по данному вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хочу заметить еще, что не хорошая практика возвращать null, можно это все обернуть в `Optional<T>`, и еще `findAny()` в методе `getAllProjects()` подразумевает возвращение одного значения из стрима в обертке Optional, но Ваш метод возвращает `List<Project>`.

Для того, чтобы избежать описанной Вами проблемы:

1. Замените `getAll()` в вызове на `findAll()`. Данный метод возвращает список объектов `Project` вместо `Object`.
2. Или приводите к типу `Project` в лямбда-выражении

   `.filter(((Project)project) -> project.getId() == companyId)`

Разумеется, первый подход предпочтительнее. Отметьте мой ответ, если он помог Вам.

Comment: Отметил как полезный, благодарю за правки!

Answer (score 1):

1. Советую вам ещё раз хорошо подумать - стоит ли делать фильтрацию в памяти. Если у вас есть строгие гарантии что `projectRepository.findAll()` никогда не вернет большое кол-во объектов и будет вызываться редко - то Ваш подход с фильтрацией в памяти с использованием Stream уместен. Иначе, создайте в репозитории отдельный метод, который умел бы фильтровать проекты по companyId и вызывайте внутри сервиса именно его (или можно сделать на уровне репозитоиря метод, который принимает универсальный фильтр, например, через Criteria API).
2. Ещё один важный момент - если ваш метод возвращает список, то он никогда не должен возвращать null. Это очень плохая практика. Если у вас нет объектов - просто верните пустой список.
3. Непонятно, чем различаются методы `projectRepository.findAll()` и `projectRepository.getAll()`. Исходя из их названия напрашивается вывод, что они делают одно и тоже. В таком случае у вас дублирование кода. Если они делают разные вещи - то переименуйте один из методов так, чтобы это было сразу понятно.
4. Транзакции желательно делать на уровен сервиса.
5. Соблюдайте последовательность в наименовании методов. Если на уровне репозитория метод называется findAll(), то и на уровне сервиса его метод-обертка должен называться точно также.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ по теме! Учту.